# Fastest power play goal in the history of the NHL

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, scoring, postseason, stanley-cup

Alexander Ovechkin, captain of the Washington Capitals scored 2 seconds in the power play, late in the first period of game 1 of Eastern Conference finals of the 2017-2018 Stanley Cup playoffs.

What are the fastest power play goals ever scored in the regular season and postseason in the history of the NHL?

Comment: It won't be much quicker than that :-p  I suppose there's probably some crazy example where someone scored directly from the faceoff.  Or certainly something where it went straight to a shot, like [this](https://www.nhl.com/video/tarasenko-scores-off-a-faceoff/t-277350912/c-45161503).  But doubt you'll get an official record when it's going to be such quick values, and no one likely bothers precisely timing such!

Answer (score 3):

Adrian Kempe of the LA Kings broke the record on January 9, 2020. He scored 1 second (actually 0.9, since it was inside the last minute of the period and the clock was showing tenths) into the power play directly off the faceoff.

https://www.nhl.com/kings/video/kempes-second-of-the-night/t-277443716/c-5070034

https://www.espn.com/nhl/boxscore/_/gameId/401145727

Power play started at 19:50 of period 3. Goal scored at 19:51 of period 3.

Answer (score 1):

Alex Ovechkin appears to have at least tied this record in looking at the Game Stats of the Caps' 6 to 0 win over the Canes on April 20, 2019.  In P3 there is a penalty call at 10:12 and Ovie's PPG is at 10:14.